# Installing ArcGIS collector on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, arcgis-collector

I have two volunteers using iPhones with ArcGIS collector, but cannot get Collector installed on one of them.

iPhone 5 running 6.1.2 installs fine however, the other, an iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1.3. does not install.

Obviously I may have to get them to upgrade their OS as the message says but I am curious to know why this would be happening.

Is there something that has changed with Collector recently or any suggestions to get collector working with iOS 6?

[image: Install message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phone with 6.1.2 must have had an older version of Collector installed and when you try to update it from iTunes it will continue to reinstall the older version of Collector (from 2013) that supported iOS 6.

The current (10.2.7) version (and all Collector versions since 2/2014) require at least iOS 7.  We needed at least iOS 7 in order to support downloading maps.

You need to update to the latest iOS on **both** devices in order to get the current version of Collector.